# Spring when is HTTPSession created if all controllers are singleton

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am learning Spring 3 and trying to understand when is HTTPSession created and what is the lifecycle. All my controllers are singleton (which is by default) and I have configured a `HttpSessionListener`. I observed that `sessionCreated` is never getting invoked.

But when I make my `LoginController` as `Session` scoped controller then the `sessionCreated` gets invoked. I want to know how is the `HttpSession` managed by spring controllers. Also, another question is lets say first request from borowser comes to `LoinController` and creates the `HttpSession` - then does the subsequent requests from that browser to different controller(which is singleton) would be using the same HTTPSession or woule it be stateless? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers are singleton and stateless. The dispatcher servlet invokes the desired controller method and passes the session to it. The session is obtained by the dispatcher servlet by calling `request.getSession()`. Since it is s normal servlet, the container "gives" it the request and response that any servlet obtains on each request.

That said, a servlet is also singleton (it has one instance per context). And multiple threads (= requests) are invoking its methods.

And a final note - session-scoped beans are rarely needed. In my experience you can have a whole application without any session-scoped beans.

Comment: Yes, by default controllers are singleton but they can configured to be session scoped by using the annotaion. If I have a mix of session scoped and singleton controllers then do they share the same HTTPSession for all requests from same browser?

Comment: @integral_dev the difference is that the session-scoped controllers can have state - i.e. you can assign values to their fields and they will be unique for each user session..

Answer (score 0):

A session associates a number of HTTP requests, so once it's created for a user the servlet engine maintains it either using cookies or URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, session associates multiple requests - but even if its forwarded to singleton controllers? Also, how is the lifecyle of that session maintained by servelet engine.